# Symfony "Invalid credentials"

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, entity, symfony5

I'm developing my first Symfony project and so far pretty good except for the Login since the warning "invalid credentials" started popping up everytime I try to log in and don't really know why because I'm using AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator instead of AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator (the one I see the most), which is driving me a bit crazy because there is not much info.

User entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @method string getUserIdentifier()
 */
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Booking", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $userBooking;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     */
    public function setName($name): void
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $email
     */
    public function setEmail($email): void
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returning a salt is only needed, if you are not using a modern
     * hashing algorithm (e.g. bcrypt or sodium) in your security.yaml.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt(): ?string
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }
}
```

Security controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        // if ($this->getUser()) {
        //     return $this->redirectToRoute('target_path');
        // }

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout")
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }
}
```

LoginFormAuthenticator:

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\PassportInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): PassportInterface
    {
        $email = $request->request->get('email', '');

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $email);

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($email),
            new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', '')),
            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->get('_csrf_token')),
            ]
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example:
        //return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('some_route'));
        //throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
        return new RedirectResponse('home');
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

Create User:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\UserTypeUser;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class NewUserController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/newuser', name: 'new_user', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function index(Request $request): Response
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserTypeUser::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $user->setRoles(['ROLE_USER']);
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        }

        return $this->render('new_user/index.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This looks fine. How do you create the user? Do you hash the password using Symfony's UserPasswordHasher (or encoder instead of hasher if you are not yet on Symfony 5.3)?

Comment: I created the user using the maker bundle. I don't encode the password, the "algorithm" field is set in "auto" at the moment.
I think I'm going to try deleting the current login files and install it again with enable_authenticator_manager set to false because I realized I have it set in true that's why I got the experimental authenticator.

Comment: That is ok. Experimental does not mean that it doesn't work or it's sketchy. It just means that between versions there might be some changes you need to account for. I think the problem is with how you register/signup/create your user. Can you add the code?

Comment: Sure thing, even though it's the same code I use for the Users create from the CRUD, just not in the same file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `NewUserController` you need to hash the password before you persist the user.

First you need to inject the service into the controller:

```php
private $passwordHasher;

public function __construct(UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordHasher)
{
    $this->passwordHasher = $passwordHasher;
}
```

Then in your action you need to add one line inside the if condition:

```php
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $user->setRoles(['ROLE_USER']);

    $user->setPassword($this->passwordHasher->hashPassword($user, $user->getPassword());

    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entityManager->persist($user);
    $entityManager->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
}
```

This assumes that you already set the password in your form, but it's not properly encoded yet. You can find this in the docs here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#c-hashing-passwords

Be careful, prior to Symfony 5.3 the password hasher was called password encoder and lived inside the security component. The code is fundamentally the same, but the class looks a bit different. See: https://symfony.com/doc/5.2/security.html#c-encoding-passwords

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't realize that by default the app reads all passwords as encoded even the ones which aren't (all accounts I was testing the app with were inserted into the database manually) so I will definetely take that into account now for future projects. Is there any way to disable the encoder?

Comment: If you just want to add the accounts in the database directly, you can also use a console command for hashing a password that you can then copy: `php bin/console security:encode-password` (you can find it in the same docs section at the very end).

Comment: You can effectively disable the hasher by using the plaintext hasher.  Just change auto to plaintext in security.yaml.  Use bin/console security:hash-password to confirm.